# Hello. I want to update input box field. Dont know what is wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need help with this code. I want to update input box field, but seems like my JavaScript wont work. There is code bellow. I need to update "pretBrojPrasadi" field, but nothing happens. Thanks for any assistance.

This is JavaScript code. I've included it into the index.php page

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function (){" "}
      {$("#pretpostavkaPrasad").click(function () {
        var brojOdeljenja = $('input[name="brojOdeljenja"]').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "pretpostavkaPrasad.php",
          data: {
            pretpostavkaPrasad: 1,
            brojOdeljenja: brojOdeljenja,
          },
          success: function (response) {
            // Update the input field
            $("#pretBrojPrasadi").val(response);
    
            // Update the result div (if needed)
            $("#result").html("Total Sum: " + response);
          },
          error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred");
          },
        });
      })}
      );
    </script>;
```

This is index.php page. In it input box "pretBrojPrasadi" should be updated

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
        <title>Prasence</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="pretpostavka.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/prasence.jpg" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stilovi.css" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titan+One&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <header class="zaglavlje">
          <img src="img/prasence.jpg" alt="logo" width="200 px" />
          <h1>Prasence</h1>
          <button id="pri" class="prijava"><a href="login.php">Prijava</a></button>
          <button id="reg" class="prijava">
            <a href="forma.php">Registracija</a>
          </button>
        </header>
        <nav class="navigacija">
          <button class="dugme">
            <a href="index.php">Početna</a>
          </button>
          <button class="dugme">
            <a href="stale.html.php">Štale</a>
          </button>
          <button class="dugme">
            <a href="krmace.php">Krmače</a>
          </button>
    
          <button class="dugme">
            <a href="galerija.php">Galerija</a>
          </button>
        </nav>
        <main>
          <section>
            
            <form id="prasenje" action="podnesiPrasenje.php" method="POST">
              <label class="prasenja" for="turnus">Broj turnusa</label>
              <input type="number" name="turnus" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="datum">Datum prašenja</label>
              <input id="datum" type="date" name="datum" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="krmaca">Broj krmače</label>
              <input id="krm" type="text" name="krmaca" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="boks">Broj boksa</label>
              <input id="boks" type="number" name="boks" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="ukupno">Ukupno oprašenih</label>
              <input id="ziv" type="number" name="ukupno" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="zivi">Zivooprašeni</label>
              <input id="stl" type="number" name="zivi" /> <br />
              <button class="podnesi3" type="submit" name="podnesak">Podnesi</button>
            </form>
          </section>
          <section>
            
            <form id="uginuca" action="podnesiUginuca.php" method="POST">
            <label class="prasenja" for="datumUginuca">Datum uginuća</label>
              <input id="datum" type="date" name="datumUginuca" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="brojUginuca">Broj uginulih prasadi</label>
              <input id="boks" type="number" name="brojUginuca" /> <br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="boksUginuca">Broj boksa</label>
              <input id="boks" type="number" name="boksUginuca" /> <br />
              <button class="podnesi5" type="submit" name="podnesakUginuca">Podnesi</button>
            </form>
          </section>
          <section>
    <form id="prebacivanje" action="prebacivanje.php" method="POST">
    <label class="prasenja" for="datumPrebacivanja">Datum prebacivanja</label>
              <input id="datum" type="date" name="datumPrebacivanja" /> <br /><br />
    <label class="prasenja" for="brojPrasadi">Broj prasadi</label>
              <input type="number" name="brojPrasadi" /> <br /><br />
    <label class="prasenja" for="prebacivanje">Prebacivanje iz boksa</label>
              <input type="number" name="prebacivanje" /> <br /><br>
              <label class="prasenja" for="prebacivanje2">Prebacivanje u boks</label>
              <input type="number" name="prebacivanje2" /> <br />
    
              <button class="podnesi" type="submit" name="prebacivanjeDugme">Podnesi</button>
    </form>
    
    
          </section>
    
          <section>
    <form id="zalucenje" action="zalucenje.php" method="POST">
    <label class="prasenja" for="datumZalucenja">Datum zalučenja</label>
              <input id="datum" type="date" name="datumZalucenja" /> <br /><br />
    <label class="prasenja" for="zalucenje">Broj zalučenih prasadi</label>
              <input type="number" name="zalucenje" /> <br /><br><br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="brojTurnusa">Broj turnusa</label>
              <input type="number" name="brojTurnusa" /> <br /><br />
              <label class="prasenja" for="brojOdeljenja">Broj odeljenja</label>
              <input type="number" name="brojOdeljenja" /> <br /><br />
              
        
              
             
              
              <button class="podnesi" type="submit" name="zalucenaPrasad">Podnesi</button>
    </form>
    <form id="zalucenje2">
        <label class="prasenja" for="brojOdeljenja">Broj odeljenja</label>
        <input type="number" name="brojOdeljenja" />
        <br /><br />
        <label class="prasenja" for="pretBrojPrasadi">Pretpostavljeni broj prasadi</label>
        <input type="number" name="pretBrojPrasadi" id="pretBrojPrasadi" value=""/>
        <button class="podnesi" type="button" id="pretpostavkaPrasad">Podnesi</button><br /><br />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    
    <form id="zalucenje3" action="razlikaPrasad.php" method="POST">
    <label class="prasenja" for="razBrojPrasadi">Razlika</label>
              <input type="number" name="razBrojPrasadi" /> <br />
    </form>
          </section>
    
    
          
           
              
              
            <form id="promene" action="odjava.php" method="POST">
            <label class="unosi" for="odjava">Odjavi se </label>
            <button class="podnesi2" type="submit" name="odjava">Odjava</button>
        </form>
              
        
            <?php 
            error_reporting(0);
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);
            echo $_SESSION["user_id"];
            
            ?>
            
          </section>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is php code that does arithmetic

```
<?php
    
    session_start();
    include 'konekcija.php'; // Include your database connection
    
    if (isset($_POST["pretpostavkaPrasad"])) {
        if (isset($_POST['brojOdeljenja'])) {
    
            echo "Slavoljub";
            $user_id= $_SESSION["user_id"];
            $brojOdeljenja = $_POST['brojOdeljenja'];
        
    
            // Step 1: Fetch the array of data from the first table
            $sql = "SELECT brojBoksa FROM boksevi WHERE brojObjekta = $brojOdeljenja AND userId=$user_id" ; // Add the correct condition to match the rows you want
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
            
            
            if ($result) {
                $totalSum = 0; // Initialize the total sum
    
                // Step 2: Iterate through the array and sum data from the second table
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $data_to_match = $row['brojBoksa'];
    
                    // Construct the SELECT query for the second table to fetch the data to sum
                    $select_sql = "SELECT trenutniBroj FROM prasenjetrenutno WHERE brojBoksa = '$data_to_match'"; // Replace 'column_to_sum' and 'second_table' with your actual column name and table name
                    $select_result = $mysqli->query($select_sql);
    
                    if ($select_result) {
                        // Sum the data obtained from the SELECT query
                        while ($select_row = $select_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $sum = $select_row['trenutniBroj'];
                            $totalSum += $sum;
                           
                        }
                     
                        $select_result->free(); // Free the SELECT result set
                    } else {
                        echo "Error fetching data from the second table: " . $mysqli->error;
                    }
                }
    
            echo  $totalSum;
    
                $result->free(); // Free the result set
            } else {
                echo "Error fetching data from the first table: " . $mysqli->error;
            }
    
        } else {
            echo "Parametri nisu prosleđeni!";
        }
        
        
    }
    $mysqli->close(); // Close the database connection
    ?>
  
    enter code here
```

It wont update. Actually nothing happens. Grateful for any help.

Comment: In `$(document).ready(function (){" "}` what do you expect `{" "}` to mean? I would get rid of `{" "}` and try again.

Comment: Could you please backtrack and let us know what is going on? Is the http request sending the correct payload? Is the data coming into the server by echoing the data? Is the value being added to the db?